# MySQL 5.7.18: Foreign key constraints and ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN from NULL to NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

The following SQL script works with MySQL 5.16.17 and older, but not with **one** of my MySQL 5.7.18 installations (the other one, MySQL 5.7.18 launched in a Docker container, is OK as well)

```
drop table if exists bar;
drop table if exists foo;

create table foo (foo_id int not null primary key, description varchar(32));
insert into foo values ("1", "foo-one");
insert into foo values ("2", "foo-two");

create table bar (bar_id int not null primary key, foo_id int null, description varchar(32), foreign key (foo_id) references foo(foo_id));
insert into bar values ("1", "1", "bar-one");
insert into bar values ("2", "1", "bar-two");

alter table bar change column foo_id foo_id int not null;
```

The error message is:

```
Error Code: 1832. Cannot change column 'foo_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'bar_ibfk_1'
```

The problems seems to be changing a column with a foreign key constraint from NULL to NOT NULL.

I know I could just wrap the last statement in a "SET foreign_key_checks..." call, but I am be interested in whether there are any system variables or configuration settings that influence the behavior of MySQL in this case, because I cannot explain the different behavior between two 5.7.18 instances.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You can tell us the value of the `SQL_MODE` variable. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xtPue5iZnMoHhR5S7cBQKZ/2).

Comment: sql_mode in 5.7.18 local installation:
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION


sql_mode in 5.7.18 Docker container:
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION


(Yes, I disabled STRICT_TRANS_TABLES in the locally installed instance to see whether this has any effect, to no avail)

Comment: With db-fiddle, the snippet fails with 5.6 and runs with 5.5 and 5.7. Interesting...

Comment: See [Bug #77591 ALTER TABLE does not allow to change NULL/NOT NULL if foreign key exists](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77591).

Answer (score 7):

you can set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS  to zero

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

alter table bar change column foo_id foo_id int not null;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```